# Arithmetization of Turing machines

Tags: first-order-logic, foundations, philosophy, turing-machines

Refer to  [Turing's 1936 paper](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Erobins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf), page 248, last paragraph. I present the paragraph in verbatim below :

> The expression "there is a general process for determining..." has been used throughout this section as equivalent to "there is a machine which will determine ... ". This usage can be justified if and only if we can justify our definition of "computable". For each of these "general process" problems can be expressed as a problem concerning a general process for determining whether a given integer n has a property G(n) [e.g. G{n) might mean "n is satisfactory" or "n is the Godel representation of a provable formula"], and this is equivalent to computing a number
> whose n-th. figure is 1 if G (n) is true and 0 if it is false.

Recall that in his paper, a machine is *satisfactory* iff machine never gets stuck. The method to determine if machine ever prints a symbol (0, 1) can be used to determine if machine is satisfactory, which is equivalent to determining if machine halts.

It has been stated in the paper that :

> To each computable sequence there corresponds at least one description number, while to no description number does there correspond more than one computable sequence. The computable sequences and numbers are therefore enumerable.

With this I have no problem.

What I am unable to understand is why is the following true:

> *statement that a particular computer program halts is ultimately just a statement about integers* [[Scott Aaronson](https://scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec3.html)].

Observe that in the first paragraph, Turing has made essentially the same assertion.

*All* we did was encoding of machines using integers. Why does that allow us to say that property of machine is property of integers? Whether machine halts is a property of *machine*, not of integers.

So why are we saying, "*each of these "general process" problems can be expressed as a problem concerning a general process for determining whether a given integer n has a property G(n) [e.g. G{n) might mean "n is satisfactory" or "n is the Godel representation of a provable formula*" [Turing], and "*statement that a particular computer program halts is **ultimately** just a statement about integers*" ?

Comment: The point is just that the "mechanical" statement "Machine number $M$ halts on input $c$" is true if and only if the corresponding "arithmetical" statement $\exists z T(M,c,z)$ (using the [T predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_T_predicate)). Whether or not these two statements are "about" the same thing may be a philosophically interesting question but it is beside the point for the particular mathematical purposes Turing, Aaronson, etc. are focusing on. Generally I think this sort of question is a better fit for Phil.SE.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Can it be explained without invoking T predicate? On what basis/reasoning did Turing made the statement that : *"each of these "general process" problems can be expressed as a problem concerning a general process for determining whether a given integer n has a property G(n)"*  ?

Comment: Sure - the T-predicate is just an efficient way of packaging what Turing was talking about. The point is that the basic steps of a Turing machine can be implemented arithmetically; the key trick here is to code *finite sequences* by individual numbers, which is either trivial or requires some Chinese Remainder Theorem cleverness depending on whether or not you have exponentiation as basic in your language (if you don't have it, you need to use something like Godel's $\beta$ function). But this is no different, fundamentally, to the arithmetization of *sytnax* in Godel's incompleteness theorem.

Comment: Incidentally, while the original paper definitely has historical interest, I would really recommend using a more modern source (as time goes on proofs get clarified/cleaned up/improved in various ways).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Okay. What is considered as an authoritative text on this topic - for technical and complete proofs?